# How should I implement the following requirements description

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is my code:
In init, I receive uncountable variables. In some subquery queries, I use variables, but in the final executed function, I don't know what variable values I need to enter.

```
 class QueryModule:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

        self.auou = AbpUserOrganizationUnits
        self.au = AbpUsers

    def get(self, k):
        if hasattr(self, k):
            return getattr(self, k)

    def own_departmentId(self):
        return session.query(self.auou.OrganizationUnitId).join(
            self.au, self.auou.UserId == self.au.Id).filter(
            self.au.HisKey == self.get('u_code')).subquery()

    def depart_query(self):
        return session.query(self.auou.OrganizationUnitId).join(
            self.au, self.auou.UserId == self.au.Id).filter(
            self.au.HisKey == self.get('u_code')).subquery()

    def current_department(self):
        department_id_list = session.query(self.depart_query()).all()
        return department_id_list


print(QueryModule(u_code='xmin').current_department())
```

In the above code, [own_departmentid] and [part_query] need to reference the variable [u_code], but I finally call the [current_department] function.

When calling the [current_department] function, I actually don't know which variable values need to be passed in.

So, is there any way to rewrite my code and let me know which parameters should be passed when I only call the function [current_department]?

Comment: There seems to be a lot missing in your example.  Have you set up an sqlalchemy session? You seem to be referring to global variables (Abp...) A clearer problem statement is needed

Comment: Yes,I have set up an SQLAlchemy session，self.au... represents a table

Comment: Did I not describe it clearly？
Is there anyone can  help me solve this problem？

Comment: You question is really hard to understand. I answered guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Doing setattr(self, k, v) is hackish and does not help you here at all. How about:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.query_args = kwargs
    self.auou = AbpUserOrganizationUnits
    self.au = AbpUsers
```

Now you have the query args stored and you can use them any time later. For example:

```
def depart_query(self):
    q = session.query(self.auou.OrganizationUnitId).join(
        self.au, self.auou.UserId == self.au.Id)
    for (k, v) in self.query_args.items():
        q = q.filter(getattr(self.au, k) == v)
    return q.subquery()
```